# Checkbox issue on ios safari

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

[Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCPaG.png)

I am facing this issue only for ios safari. this checkbox working ok for other platforms.
I cant inspect to apply the styling.
On web safari its working fine as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue with a button. This line of code fixed it for me.

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Comment: i applied that one and it just remove all type of styling from all platfrom